# Latex on Bootable CD (700mb) with Minimal Operating System

Tags: installing

I want to use latex with a minimal operating system that will run from bootable cd. One  of the  option is texnix. http://sourceforge.net/projects/texnix . Any other option with good tex editor (texworks or texmaker). Actually I want to run it from Computer Systems that do not have hard discs but have RAM of 1 GB. Knoppix DVD and Mathlibre are other options, but they are available only on DVD. I want it on CD.

Comment: LaTeX is big unless you have very firm limits on what you will need. However, if your minimal system will connect to the internet, then there may be some online solutions -- e.g., [Overleaf](http://www.overleaf.com) and/or [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com). This solves the size problem, but perhaps introduces other problems.

Comment: Note also: [MathLibre](http://www.mathlibre.org/about.html) seems to include "TeX System" right from installation, so if you loosen up your space requirements, this might be a viable option.  Note, however, that many Linux distributions offer their own pre-packaged version of a *TeX ecosystem, but that it is usually not so up to date.

Answer (score 1):

What do mean with "I want to use LaTeX"?

To use LaTeX you need an editor and a TeX distribution like TeX Live (Unix, Linux or Windows) or MiKTeX (Windows).  To be able to use all possibilities of your distribution you should use (after installing) the complete distribution on your CD.

The complete version of MiKTeX for example needs a download of < 2 GB.  So you can't create a bootable cd (with which OS? That needs space too!) including a complete MIKTeX (or TeX Live).

There is a portable version of MiKTeX but in the base version it has not much functions.  The portable version is able to download and install missing packages, but you can't write on on CD (of course you have not enouph space for that too).

If you want to use a portable version of MiKTeX or TeX Live you can use a bootable USB stick with the advantage to be able to add new packages on the stick if neccessary. I would use an stick with more than 4 GB.

**Conclusion:** 
With an CD it is not usefull, but with an USB Stick you can do it. Depending on the size of the stick you can install editors etc. and keep your portal system up to date.

Comment: I think your comments are on point except for the stuff about MikTeX. The distributions named in the question are all varieties of Linux, so MikTeX is not going to be an option. (Not that TeX Live is significantly smaller -- as I'm sure you know.)

Comment: I think the answer is mostly good, but mention of portable MiKTeX makes absolutely no sense (whether it is good or bad, whether it would fit on the same CD or not) since it is impossible to use with any of the distributions the OP mentions.  My point is more that all mention of MiKTeX could be dropped from your answer because when you're running Linux, you kind of have to not care what is or is not possible with MiKTeX....